# Outlook Mail REST API (Office 365) using PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, outlook

I try to update a mail message using PowerShell and the REST API described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#UpdateMessages

I try to set the flag to true like this:

```
$uri='https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/AQMkAGNhMTJjZjJkLWJkYzEtNDY0My1hNTZhLWVmZgA2YTk1NjE2ZDYARgAAA_7Xl9tlI5pJjN-oWribDGQHAFOydA6gG1ZPhkRvyZErSPAAAAIBDAAAAFOydA6gG1ZPhkRvyZErSPAAAAIBfwAAAA=='

$contentType="application/json"

$body="{""IsRead"": true }"

$mail=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri-ContentType $contentType -Body $body-Credential $MailCred -Method Patch
```

I always get a 403 error. I tried the v2.0 API as v1.0 API as well?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does passing credentials create an access token? Or do you need to manually attach that to the request? That is my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised to use

`https://outlook.office365.com`
instead of 
`https://outlook.office.com/`

This should help.

Thank you,
Yuriy